# How to sort category posts alphabetically in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Sorry about that but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.
I am trying to sort my posts from category #3 alphabetically but I think I'm doing it wrong.

```
<?php
    $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=3' );
    while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post('&orderby=title&order=ASC');
?>
```

Comment: Ordering happens inside the query, not “in” an individual post. (What sense would it make to sort _one_ post by anything? One single item has the same “order” any time anywhere, no matter what criterion you apply.)

Comment: Thanks, sorry I'm a bit new in php :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'cat' => 3
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

    $catquery = new WP_Query($args);
    while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
```

Hope help you.

Comment: thanks it works with some adjustments :
'cat' => 3,
    'order' => 'ASC'

Answer (score 1):

try sort from query itself

```
$args = [
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'orderby' => 'title',
        ];

        $query = new WP_Query($args);
```